# Each cluster of data frame on separate page of pdf file

Tags: r

I will use `mtcars` data frame as an example. I would like to print two columns of the data frame on each page of pdf file depending on the cluster which they belong.

```
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
```

Let's assume that column `carb` is the cluster column. As you see we have 4 different clusters so what I would like to do is to put the output of two columns (starting from the first one) on separate page in pdf.

First page should look like:

1. Datsun 710          22.8
2. Hornet 4 Drive      21.4
3. Valiant             18.1

Second page should look like:

1. Hornet Sportabout   18.7
2. Merc 240D           24.4
3. Merc 230            22.8

Third page should look like:

1. Merc 450SE          16.4

And I believe that you already know how the output of the last page should look like. Can you help me with that ? My data frame contains in total around 250 clusters.

Comment: I think you can split the dataset with the subset columns using `lst <- split(mtcars[1], mtcars$carb)` and you can save the list output to a pdf

Comment: Also check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937131/print-to-pdf-file-using-grid-table-in-r-too-many-rows-to-fit-on-one-page)

Comment: Sounds fair. Can you write an answer and show me how to save the output of list in pdf ? I would like to reward you for the solution. It looks fine.

Comment: I tried the `pdf('somefile.pdf');lapply(lst, grid.table)` but it is overwriting in a single page.  I haven't tried the solution in the link though.  If you can test it and get it working, you can post that as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grid.newpage() forces each table to appear on a new page,

```
pdf("multipage.pdf")
lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$carb), function(d) {
  grid::grid.newpage()
  gridExtra::grid.table(d)
  }
  )
dev.off()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. It puts a whole table as an output but I can live with that. Do you know how I can change the font size in pdf file or how to make a table smaller because I don't see all of the rows.

Comment: [it's now officially a FAQ](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki#problems-with-gridtable)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the @baptiste's answer here is a solution using rmarkdown. In order to print each table on a new pdf page you have to set `results='asis'`. With `cat("\n\n\\newpage")` and `cat("\n\n\##")` you can then dynamically create new pages and headers. `knitr::kable()` provides a nice table output.

````
---
title: "mtcars_clusters"
author: "Your name"
date: "3 August 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
DAT <- lapply(sort(unique(mtcars$carb)), function(cluster) {
      data <- subset(mtcars, carb == cluster)
      cat(paste("\n\n## Cluster", cluster))
      print(knitr::kable(data))
      cat("\n\n\\newpage")
})
```
````

**EDIT: Example with a larger data set**

With respect to your comment on @baptiste's answer this markdown approach also handles larger data sets better. Here is an example with the `ChickWeight` dataset using `ChickWeight$Diet` as cluster variable:

````
---
title: "ChickWeight_clusters"
author: "Your name"
date: "3 August 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
DAT <- lapply(sort(unique(ChickWeight$Diet)), function(cluster) {
  data <- subset(ChickWeight, Diet == cluster)
  cat(paste("\n\n## Cluster", cluster))
  print(knitr::kable(data))
  cat("\n\n\\newpage")
})
```
````

The output table is automatically split between pages so you should see all rows. Also, if you only want to print specific columns just subset `data` within `print(knitr::kable(data))` accordingly.